# What is the best time and temperature for taste when cooking a salmon fillet in the oven?

Tags: oven, cooking-time, temperature, salmon

I have an Atlantic salmon fillet in my frig at the moment, but I really have no idea what the normal cooking temperature and time are for a salmon fillet.

What's the best temp and time to cook a 1lb salmon fillet in the oven?

Comment: Why cook in the oven? My favorite is fried in butter :)

Comment: For some reason frying stuff scares me, and I've become obsessed with the oven.  It's the lazy mans grill!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you're determining the doneness by time, you're doing it wrong :)

There are too many differences between individual fish to go just by weight, thickness, oven temperature, and time. The best way is to measure the *internal* temperature (stick a thermometer into the thickest part of the fillet); I like about 120 F (50 C) for salmon (carryover cooking raises the temperature a little higher after taking it out of the pan), but then it has to be good quality fish. You need to check **early** and **often**, because it can go from undercooked to overcooked fairly quickly. Now, like zanlok says, my experience is mostly with pan frying, and I'd expect using the oven would be a bit slower than using a pan because of slower heat transfer; so you should be a bit safer.

If you don't have a meat thermometer, an easy way to test fish for doneness is to look for translucency. Salmon can still be just a little translucent in the middle. Also, properly done fish flakes along the natural "seams". Another nice trick (which doesn't work for boneless fillets - sorry) is to find a bone in the thickest part of the fish: if it comes out fairly easily, then the connective tissues have mostly dissolved and it's done.

That leaves the temperature for your oven. I would go with very high - that way the fish gets the least possible time to dry out (which is going to be a big risk with this cooking method, I would think - unless you wrap your salmon in bacon or something like that). At a guess, I'd try 450 F (230 C).

Comment: Salmon needs to be significantly overcooked before drying out, since it's so fatty. I usually cook it at 350 F, and check often. Otherwise, your comments are spot on.

Answer (score 0):

I wrapped the fillet in foil and cooked it for 42 minutes at about 375°F (190°C).

It was delicious.