# What is the smoking point of salmon fillet oil?

Tags: oil, oven, salmon

What is the [smoking point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smoke_point) of salmon fillet oil cooking in oven (baked in a foil parcel)? (could be a range)

There is one Q&A at [What is the best time and temperature for taste when cooking a salmon fillet in the oven?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/11253/what-is-the-best-time-and-temperature-for-taste-when-cooking-a-salmon-fillet-in), but it doesn't answer what's the smoking point.

Comment: I don't understand your question. What is "salmon filet oil"? Also, why are you asking such a question? Normally, you don't reach any smoking points in the oven.

Comment: Every oil has a smoking point and few times cooking salmon fillet at high temperature it produced a lot of smoke in the oven, therefore I'm wondering what's the smoking point of oil which is produced from cooking salmon fillet.

Comment: That depends on what oil you added, if any.

Comment: I didn't add any, but usually salmon fillet produces enough oil by it-self.

Comment: True, it's a fairly oily fish, but I've never seen oil leaking out of the flesh while cooking (the same way that solid fats can render on red meat, for example).  The smoke could be coming from elsewhere.  Not to be flip, but I think if your salmon is smoking, it's probably at too high a temperature.  The accepted answer in your linked question advises a high temp to avoid drying out but that's less problematic when cooking in a properly sealed foil packet.

Comment: @kenorb I haven't seen salmon rendering fat in the oven. Nor have I seen an oven bringing a pool of oil to its smoke point, unless it was at the rotisserie setting. Maybe your fat dripped onto the bottom, or even the heating elements if they are exposed. This doesn't matter, because you don't eat this fat.

Comment: I wonder if the smoke point might depend on what all is suspended in the oil - for example, "whole" butter smokes at a much lower temperature than clarified butter which is just the oil without other milk components, and have heard similar things for "crude" vs refined forms of oils such as coconut.  As to a salmon fillet exuding oil, I do remember seeing this years ago, but not recently.  Perhaps the fat content of typical samples has changed, or perhaps it's just that my current convection oven can't get it anywhere near as hot as the ordinary oven I used to have.

Answer (score 1):

According to this anecdotal Reddit post [1], salmon oil holds up to 460F, 232C. However, most fish oils are considered unstable and unsuitable for cooking as their Inherent Oxidation Stability is relatively high [2].

[1] https://www.reddit.com/r/AskCulinary/comments/7dx0cp/fish_oil_as_a_cooking_fat

[2] http://www.clovegarden.com/ingred/oilchart.html